# classID/UUID of a Camera in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, camera

Or how to identify a camera in actionscript 3?

Comment: You may be more likely to get a response if you go back and accept some answers to previous questions.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

[`Camera.names`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#names) is the only Flash Player API available that describes the number and names of cameras.

As noted by the OP, this is not useful to uniquely identify a camera. For example, if the system has two cameras that are the same make/model. In this scenario the camera names (likely OS dependent) tend to be "camera_name 1" and "camera_name 2". If these are USB cameras, the "1" and "2" are meaningless, because they merely imply which one was plugged in first.

Finally, you cannot rely on the camera's index in the `Camera.names` array either, it's also subject to the "who was plugged in first" thing.

In summary, there is no unique ID.